# Pyinstaller 3.4 not Installed Correctly?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller

After running `pip install pyinstaller`and typing in the command prompt `pyinstaller --version` I get the following traceback:

```
C:\python_programs\py_mudlog_live>pyinstaller --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 212, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.pywin32 import pywintypes  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.pywin32 import win32api
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 12, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.core import (
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\__init__.py", line 36, in load_module
    module = importlib.import_module(self.redirect_module)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 19, in <module>
    """)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 107, in cdef
    self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, packed=packed)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 167, in parse
    self._internal_parse(csource)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 173, in _internal_parse
    ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 130, in _parse
    self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 159, in convert_pycparser_error
    raise api.CDefError(msg)
cffi.api.CDefError: cannot parse "HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibraryExW(LPCTSTR lpFileName, HANDLE hFile, DWORD dwFlags);"
:16:16: before: LoadLibraryExW
```

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 2.7. Does anyone know why it's not working correctly?

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade cffi` and try again?

Comment: I ended up downgrading pyinstaller to version 3.0 and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, 3.4 has some issues with dependencies, I've been using the 3.5.dev with python 3.7, no issues so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded Pyinstaller to version 3.0 (pip install pyinstaller==3.0). The older version works fine for me.

Comment: This may be useful information, but it does not answer the question you asked.